# Can we quick let String become [Character] in swift?

Tags: swift, string

I have a String and I want get an Array of the String's Characters.

I can already do it, like this:

```
var Carr = [Character]()
for c in s.characters {
    Carr.append(c)
}
```

As you can see, it's not beautiful or efficient.

In Java, I can use `char[] sa = s.toCharArray();` to get a `char[]`. Is there a similarly simple way to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let charArray = Array(s.characters)
```

[`String.characters`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1540072-characters) is a [`String.CharacterView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string.characterview). It conforms to [`BidirectionalCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/bidirectionalcollection), which inherits from [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection), and ultimately [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence).

Because it conforms to `Sequence`, it can be used in a `for` loop, as you showed. But also, it can be used in the [initializer of Array that takes a sequence.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1538750-init)

Comment: Thank you, it really did. I try a lot of function, but forget this.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using the right function:

```
let yourString = "a string"
let characters = yourString.characters
let count = characters.count
```

This gives you the collection of characters contained in your string

Comment: a sequence of characters, not an array.

Comment: yes , it look like an array,but not an array. You can not let characters[0] = "a"